# How to use sum in active records in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanted to know if my syntax is right, this is my model where I query using 
active records. I wanted to sum up the column 'amount' inside select however it won't work for me. I wonder id I am possibly doing it right? Should I separate the summation part?

```
function result_getAssessment()

    {
        $this->db->select('register.regnum,register.studentid,accountspayable.accountno,accountspayable.accounttype,accountspayable.amount,sum(amount) AS sum');
        $this->db->from('accountspayable');
        $this->db->join('register', 'accountspayable.regnum = register.regnum');
        $this->db->where('accountspayable.regnum','15459');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();


    }
```

This is how I call it in the views:

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row){ ?>


                   <?php echo $row->regnum;?> <br>
                   <?php echo $row->studentid;?> <br>
                   <?php echo $row->accountno;?> <br>
                   <?php echo $row->accounttype;?>  <br>
                   <?php echo $row->amount;?><br>
                   <?php echo $row->sum;?><br>


    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: your syntax is right but your process is wrong. By this process you wont achieve what you want to do. echo $this->db->last_query() then execute your query in mysql and see what it is resulting.

Comment: @Vinie why can you say that my process is wrong? at which part?

Comment: What problem you are getting can you please explain, then i'll say your process is wrong or not?

Answer (score -1):

The overall query seems to be right, but the column name does not look right to me. Instead of naming the column `sum`, try naming it something else (as `sum` is an inbuilt function), or atleast quote the sum column in backticks e.g.

```
function result_getAssessment()

    {
        $this->db->select('register.regnum,register.studentid,accountspayable.accountno,accountspayable.accounttype,accountspayable.amount,sum(accountspayable.amount) AS `sum`');
        $this->db->from('accountspayable');
        $this->db->join('register', 'accountspayable.regnum = register.regnum');
        $this->db->where('accountspayable.regnum','15459');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();


    }
```

It will be easier to debug if you provide the output that you are getting, but my gut feeling says that the problem is right there in the column name.

Edit: It also seems that you are summing up the wrong column. See the updated code.

Comment: actually it tells me that `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object ` the column im summing up is the right one. I wanted to sum up the amount